# How to count missing data in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a character matrix

```
B = matrix( 
    c("foo", "--", "bam", "pop", "--", "foo","--","fizz"), 
    nrow=2, 
    ncol=4)
```

Missing data is represented by "--". I'm trying to write a for loop that get the fraction of "--"'s in each column. If the fraction of "--" in that column is >= .5 then I want to store that column index in a separate vector called `bad_columns`. In this matrix the first column has a "--" fraction of .5, the second column has a "--" fraction of 0.

Similarly for the rows of the matrix, I'm trying to get the fraction of "--" in each row. If the fraction of "--" in the row is >= .5 then I want to store that row index in a separate vector called `bad_rows`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colSums function is very fast:

colSum(B=="--")/nrow(B)

```
> badcols <- which( colSums(B=="--")/nrow(B) >= 0.5 )
> badcols
[1] 1 3 4
```

There is, of course, also a `rowSums` function.

Comment: I'd note `rowMeans` and `colMeans` do the division by `nrow(B)` and `ncol(B)` for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty standard use of the `apply()` function with matrixes to perform operations over rows/columns. Be sure to read the `?apply` help page. Then you just use `which()` to get the indexes of the values that match your criteria.

```
bad_columns <- which(apply(B, 2, function(x) mean(x=="--")) >= .5)
bad_rows <- which(apply(B, 1, function(x) mean(x=="--")) >= .5)

bad_columns
# [1] 1 3 4
bad_rows
# [1] 1
```